# How to hide table rows based on their content

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm working on an Angular 2 application.

There is a summary sections which displays all the information encoded in the other sections.

The summary is basically a table where for each line, the first column is the name of the field and the second column is the value encoded.
The value can be displayed using {{value}} or using custom components.

When no value is encoded, the corresponding line can be hidden in the summary section by using a toggle button. The user can then decide if he wants to see the empty answers or not.

The structure of the summary page is quite simple :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Section 1</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td id="name" colspan="4">
      {{profile.name}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Travelling</th>
    <td id="travelling" colspan="4">
      <app-travelling [value]="profile.travelling"></app-travelling>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Driving licence</th>
    <td id="driving-licence" colspan="4">
      <app-driving-licence [value]="profile.drivingLicence"></app-driving-licence>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <td id="rating" colspan="4">
      <app-rating [value]="profile.rating"></app-rating>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The thing is that the summary page contains more or less 2000 lines.
I don't really want to go through the whole html and modify every `<tr>`.

Here are the different options I've thought about :

1. use ng-if on each tr

   - pretty painful to add it on each tr
2. use a custom directive on each tr

   - as painful as the ng-if but it seems a bit easier to read
3. use a custom component around the tr and use ng-content in the component

   - as painful as the 2 above
4. use jquery to find the empty values and add a specific class on the corresponding tr

   - not as painful as modifying each tr

Do you have any other idea?
Which solution would you choose?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you use ngFor ,can you share with us you code

Comment: Using *ngFor to read all the sections inside an array and inside it, use *ngIf in each tr that needs a condition to show could be your solution, but maybe the best choice it's using an angular table component that have implemented that and a lot of more funcionality. For example, take a look to angular material table: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score 1):

Try by using this function an iterate every element.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...

constructor(private elem: ElementRef){}

let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('tr');
    elements.forEach(element => {
     //TODO Conditional and action
   });
```